# regex delete heading and tailing punctuation

Tags: java, regex, string

I am trying to write a regex in Java to get rid of all heading and tailing punctuation characters except for `"-"` in a String, however keeping the punctuation within words intact.

1. I tried to replace the punctuations with `""`, `String regex = "[\\p{Punct}+&&[^-]]";` right now, but it will delete the punctuation within word too.
2. I also tried to match pattern: `String regex = "[(\\w+\\p{Punct}+\\w+)]";` and `Matcher.maches()` to match a group, but it gives me null for input `String word = "#(*&wor(&d#)("`

I am wondering what is the right way to deal with Regex group matching in this case

Examples:

```
Input: @)($&word@)($&                   Output: word
Input: @)($)word@google.com#)(*$&$      Output: word@google.com
```

Comment: Can you drop in some sample data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^\\p{Punct}*(.*?)\\p{Punct}*$");
    Matcher m = p.matcher("@)($)word@google.com#)(*$&$");
    if (m.matches()) {
        System.out.println(m.group(1));
    }
```

To give some more info, the key is to have marks for the beginning and end of the string in the regex (^ and $) and to have the middle part match non-greedily (using *? instead of just *).

Comment: be warned that `\p{Punct}` is an ASCII-only version of the POSIX `[[:punct:]]` character class. This (rather small) set includes characters that from the Unicode perspective fall into both `\pP` *Punctuation* and `\pS` *Symbol.* That’s because Unicode made two distinct general categories where POSIX  had only one alone.